# Not Getting the Laravel Relantionship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Student Info Table:

`id | school_info_id | roll_no | classes_id | religion | caste | parent_id | student_name`

Classes Table

`id | school_info_id | class_title | section | created_at | updated_at`

I wanted `StudentInfo->with('classes')->get()`
But not getting any.

```
class StudentInfo extends Model{
  public function classes(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Classes::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please write the code of the relationship you created

Comment: Does `StudentInfo::all()` get all the student info rows correctly?

Comment: yep, every is getting perfect, the class relanship is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `$this->belongsTo(Classes::class,'classes_id','id');` and see if that works?